# Import .txt file in TextWrangler - Insufficient memory Error code: -108

Tags: macos, text, textwrangler

I tried importing a .txt file into TextWrangler version 4.5.10, but got error code `-108`. The `.txt` file is 1.11 GB.

I have a MacBook Pro version 10.9.5.

I turned off the option to "Automatically refresh documents as they change on disk" to save memory, but had the same result.

How can I import the `.txt` file in?

Comment: did you purchase textwrangler from app store?

Comment: downloaded it for free from app store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 010 Editor and didn't have problems loading the `.txt` file.